# ng-repeat visual glitch (previous & new array displayed)

Tags: angularjs

I have a glitch with angular's ng-repeat directive. My HTML is as follow:

```
<ul ng-show="predictions" id="search-place-predictions">
  <li ng-repeat="prediction in predictions">{{prediction.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

and `$scope.predictions` is an Array in my controller, that takes between 0 and 5 items. However, at each update of this array, I have a visual glitch of around .2 second where the PREVIOUS `<li>` are still displayed, and the `<li>` from the new version of the array are also displayed on top of it. No amounts of `$apply()` have been able to solve this.

EDIT: I have a `transition: border-top .2s ease-out;` style applied to my list items. When commented out, the glitch disappears.

Comment: you want to remove old li data??

Comment: I do! I want the new array to completely replace the old one, and the list to reflect that change right away. Say I have 2 items then 5 items, my list goes from 2 items to 7 items to 5 items...

Comment: Are you including ngAnimate?

Comment: I'm not. I'm not even sure what it is :)

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: WOW Joe, following your comment I commented out my CSS animations, and now no problem...

Comment: OK so I have a `transition: border-top .2s ease-out;` on my `<li>` and when commented out, the glitch disappears. Not sure where the bug is. Is it a "feature" that I can disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, per se.  Some browsers don't support animation, but angular will still delay hiding and showing by the animation length it detects in your CSS.  Usually affects IE <= 9.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249441/disable-nganimate-for-some-elements) for ways to disable animations in angular.

Comment: thanks Joe, this looks like an interesting answer but I don't see how the resource you're linking to can help me disable animations :/

Comment: great thanks! BTW I'm getting the glitch in Ionic, which may be ill-supported by latest angular :)

Comment: For future reference: this pointed me in the right direction, however I don't use the ngAnimate module so it must be cause by something else.