# Disable Angular UI Grid column menu animation

Tags: angular-ui-grid

When I click on an Angular UI Grid column's arrow icon to show the dropdown menu for that column, then click the arrow icon again to hide it, the menu "shoots" up in an animated fashion, which I find undesirable.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: This is currently a bug due to some refactoring for IE9, it will hopefully be fixed in the next RC.

Comment: Link to related issue on github: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3921#issuecomment-118548377

Comment: I really wish there was a way to simply disable animation for ui-gird without having to remove the ngAnimate module. I want to add animation to my SPA, but because of the UI-Grid bug, I have to remove the ngAnimate module. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ngAnimate module is responsible for the animation. You can exclude that from the application. If any of your dependent js libraries require ngAnimate then this may not be possible.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
```

Example without the ngAnimate

http://plnkr.co/edit/EEI8te66R2aa4H9UFTHX?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30947122/152619), there is a generic, non-UI-Grid-specific way of disabling animations for specific elements. Note that this doesn't affect *only* animations perpetrated by `ngAnimate`; rather, this disables all animations *in general*.

From the original answer:

> Just add this to your CSS. It is best if it is the last rule:
>
> ```
> .no-animate {
>    -webkit-transition: none !important;
>    transition: none !important;
> }
> ```
>
> then add `no-animate` to the class of element you want to disable.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> <div class="no-animate"></div>
> ```

So, to disable animation of the grid's menus, do the following (using Sass, but you get the idea):

```
.ui-grid-menu-mid {
  @extend .no-animate; // the .ng-animate class is as defined above
}
```

The only real downside that I can see with this method is that you can't selectively disable animations for column and/or grid menus, only for both at the same time.