# ng-class evaluating true for an expression and its inverse

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a situation I can't figure out. `ng-class` is applying both of these classes, even though the expressions specify inverse logic. Here's the code that expresses how I want the classes to work: either `isThinking` or `notThinking`, but never both:

```
<div class="myWidget" ng-class="{
            isThinking:   vm.isThinking(),
            notThinking: !vm.isThinking()
          }"
</div>
```

The problem is that Angular applies both classes. I can't understand why.

I have investigated:

- `$digest` cycle just needs to be triggered? No, causing a digest has no effect
- Does `isThinking` always return true or false, never undefined? confirmed.
- Does changing the name of one of the classes from `notThinking` to `isReady` solve it? (testing for perhaps a too-fuzzy regex match) No, the classes still are both active at the same time.
- Does removing the second `notThinking` expression altogether cause the `isThinking` class to be properly added and removed? Yes, yes it does. Why is that, I have no idea.

Angular version is 1.4.6.

Can anyone think of a reason why both classes would be active, when the 2 expressions are clearly inverse?

Comment: Do you use ngAnimate? Does the bug happen without ngAnimate? Not really a solution but might help finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: The function just inspects the existence of a private property. It almost couldn't be any simpler. ngAnimate I should look at...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was `ngAnimate`. I haven't found a root-cause, but it's enough for me to know that [disabling animate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251562/111243) solves the problem. This element wasn't explicitly animated, but ngAnimate impacts everything unless you disable it. I presume it's a framework issue with timing the DOM manipulation.

Fix:

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
  $animate.enabled(el, false)
}
```