# Disable ng-animate globally and then enable on some elements

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Using Angular 1.5.3, is it possible to globally disable ng-animate and then selectively enable it on some elements?

I have a directive (`ng-animate-enabled`) used to enable ng-animate on the container `div` and it's children.

If I globally disable ng-animate in the controller via `$animate.enabled(false)`, the animations no longer work even though I am specifically enabling them via the directive mentioned above.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmirro/65cmfbyq/) illustrates the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`$animateProvider.classNameFilter()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider). This lets you selectively enable ngAnimate for certain elements based on a HTML class (or more specifically, a regular expressions that is checked against the class). This eliminates the need to have a specific directive for enabling ngAnimate, and can give your application a significant performance boost. In your case, I'd do:

```
// Note that that the function takes a regular expression, not a string!
// Don't put quotes around it, use forward slashes!
$animateProvider.classNameFilter(/ng-animate-enabled/);
```

Which would enable ngAnimate for any elements with the `ng-animate-enabled` class.

For more information, I'd recommend reading [Ben Nadel's blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2935-enable-animations-explicitly-for-a-performance-boost-in-angularjs.htm) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks Joe!  I just read Ben's article and he confirmed my question so I removed it (before you answered).  Also, the first comment to [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21251562/3722775) seems to clarify that my original approach above isn't possible.

Comment: @rmirro: Glad it helped you!