# block ng-animate when going to the same state

Tags: css, angularjs

(Solution is on the bottom of this post).

Currently we've a problem in our project using `ng-animate`. 
We've got two states, lets name them for now: State 1 and State 2. Both have their state name as a div class. `<div class="state1">`.

Now state1 should slide up to the top, and slide2 should slide in from the bottom. This is working fine when switching between slide1 and slide2. However, if a user clicks on another button that moves to state1 (when being on state1) then only the content should change and no animation should be done.

Currently we use: `.state1.ng-leave { }` for the leaving animation on the state1 div, and `.state2.ng-enter { }` on the entering state. As you can see, when I'm on state1 and clicking on a button that will give another page with state1 then still the `.state1.ng-leave { }` will get called and the animation will be done.

Anyone got a solution for us? The `ng-leave {}` for state1 should only be triggered as soon as state2 is entering.

[State1/State2 flow](http://i66.tinypic.com/23ql53.png)

Things we've tried:

- We tried to add something to `state('home.state1', { }` to block the `ng-animation` for state1. When you enter state1, we never need an animation. We didn't find the solution using this. Probably there is something we can add to `onExit:` what we didn't try?
- We also tried to work with ng-animate in the div.

**Preview** In this plnkr I have made an example what is going wrong. If you click "state1", you can see that the page is sliding up, but we don't want that. We just want to "refresh" the page so you just get the page without animation. If you click state2 then the animation should be done (just like the example shows). I also added a button on the state2 page that shows how the page should load when going from state1 to state1. Please check my example below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zaFcZFOEtCybRuXobYl0?p=preview

**Edit - Solution:**
The solution was kinda easy and I found it because of the accepted reaction below. In the .state() from state1 I added:

```
onEnter: function() { $('.pane-animated').removeClass('state1'); },
```

This removes the state1 class from the div (as state1 class is on the same div as "pane-animated". Just added that to remove the right class). As I applied the animation on 
.state1.ng-leave { } it cannot do the animation anymore as it doesn't have this class anymore.

Tested it serveral times, and works great!

Comment: Please add sample code on jsfiddle or codepen for us to see what is the actual problem and suggest solutions.

Comment: I added an example to show what is happening in my first post. Please check the plnkr on the bottom of the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is the issue that i see. Any anchor tag with a # is taken as a redirect by angular so what it does as your route '/' is set to home page, angular redirects on that anchor click to home page and as the home page has a ng-leave animation applied. It does the animation.

In order to achieve what you want you just need to remove the `#` from the href and keep it empty as `href=""`. Now that does not make sense as to why you would want a empty anchor but that gives you a dirty result but a result none the less (Hehe).

Now assuming you are wanting this to be done is to use the # anchor to navigate to a tag/element within the same page using hash linking. You can use the controller $anchorScroll() for it.

Example code:

```
yourapp.controller('yourControllername', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
  $location.hash(id);
  $anchorScroll();
  } 
});

<a ng-click="scrollTo('sectionA')">Foo</a>

<div id="sectionA">Here you are</div>
```

Hope this helps.

**[Edit]**

Ok after knowing your full requirement now based on your comment to this answer. I think i have come up with another solution to fit you needs. Its not perfect but it works until we find a good solution. Here is what you need to do (Keeping the sample code you shared in mind).

a) We make a new page and call it page-other.html. This will have same links buttons as home page with state 1 navigating to home using `href="#"` in anchor and state2 navigating to about as before. Just change the `<h2>Home</h2>` to `<h2>Home- Other</h2>` just to keep track where we are.

b) Add the page into the routeprovider but give it the same controller as mainController as follows:

```
.when('/other', {
        templateUrl: 'page-other.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
```

c) Add the class `page-no-animate` in the css setting it just like home page with background color etc. except for the animation part will be none as follows:

```
.page-no-animate { background:#00D0BC; color:#00907c; }

.page-no-animate.ng-enter,
.page-no-animate.ng-leave,
.page-no-animate.ng-animate {
   animation:none 0s;
   -webkit-animation: none 0s;
}
```

d) Change your mainController code to as follows. What it does is it has a function named `gotoOther` which sets the pageClass to `page-no-animate` and redirects to the other page using `$location.path("/other")`. After this funtion we have if-else condition that check on which location we are to apply appropriate animation or no-animation pageClass value as we dont want the other page to animate when we click the state 1 again to come back:

```
animateApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', 
function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.gotoOther = function () {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-no-animate';
        $location.path("other");
    };
    if ($location.path() == "/other")
    {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-no-animate';
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
    }
}]);
```

e) In you page-home.html, in the "State1" anchor tag: empty the href attribute and add the ng-click attribute to call the gotoOther function we created in the controller as follows

```
<a href="" ng-click="gotoOther()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">State1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The plnkr I made is just an example how it works. Removing the # is not possible as it has it's own page, but is within the same state (and template). Only the content is changing.

I'm going to try what you suggested. Probably with this information I can try some new work around as it seems like there is no "nice" solution to this.

Comment: I have editted the answer. I worked out a solution to the needs you described in comments. Hope it helps. Check the solution after the [Edit] part.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpfull. Because of your post I found the right solution. We're using .state() (just like I had in the example with .when() ).

Now I added there: 
onEnter: function() {
          $('.pane-animated').removeClass('state1');
      },

As state1 is animated, I only have to remove the class as soon as you don't want an animation. So when switching from 1 to 1, you can define in the onExit of the state1 to remove the class so it cannot do the animation anymore.

Comment: Nice. Glad you found the solution. Post it here with code as answer or make an edit to your question to add your solution here so that it may help others if need be.

Comment: Yes I have done that as I've seen many people asking for this also on IRC and other platforms. Glad to help them out also. I editted my post. :)

Answer (score 0):

see in jquery when ever we use animate function then we first use STOP then animate for eg : $('cntrol').stop().animate(function(--
so i think you need to find some kind of stop function in angular also so that when ever you start animate first it stops the existing animate function.

Comment: We found some posts on stackoverflow about this such as: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249441/disable-nganimate-for-some-elements). However we where not yet able to implement it. Probably because we have no clue how to inject the class before changing states as you're already in that process of switching states. Injecting classes to the div didn't give the result we're looking for probably as it doesn't effect the ng-animation anymore. Not sure though..